# How to make Visual Studio go into the #define during debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

When i am debugging my code in visual studio and it goes to a `#define` like this :

```
#define DEC_CONSTRUCTOR(a,b) line 1 \
        line 2 \
        line 3
```

and code is

```
DEC_CONSTRUCTOR ( arg1, arg2 ) {     < - LINE X
... some things ...                  < - LINE Y

};
```

When i debug point reaches `LINE X` even for one step ahead it goes to `LINE Y`.

It would be great if i could make it go through `line 1, 2 and 3` in anyway like doing something [ like some option ] and then recompiling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stepping into MACRO in VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496284/stepping-into-macro-in-vc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. #define macros are handled by the preprocessor, so the compiler cannot generate debug info for it.